# Extract domain then paste into the same line using sed/awk/grep/perl

Tags: linux, database, perl, awk, sed

I've started my tech adventure not so long ago - as you will feel from question - but now I'm stucked because after almost a whole day thinking and searching I don't know the proper solution for my problem.

Briefly, I got a file with thousand lines which contains email and firstname. The thing is I really need another column just with the domain name itself for example next to the email address. Please take a look at the examples below.

This is how it looks now:

```
    something@nothing.tld|:|george|-|
    anything@another.tld|:|thomas|-|
    third@address.tld|:|kelly|-|
```

How I wanted to look like:

```
    something@nothing.tld|:|nothing.tld|--|george|-|
    anything@another.tld|:|another.tld|--|thomas|-|
    third@address.tld|:|address.tld|--|kelly|-|
```

My best guess was using sed to start the process and extract the domain but how can I paste that extracted domain within the same line that's where I stucked.

```
    sed -e 's/.*@\(.*\)|:|*/\1/'
```

If you could also give a short explanation along with a solution that would be really helpful.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori yes, please see my updated question but I just stucked with the paste part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the following data in a file named, `file1`,

```
 something@nothing.tld|:|george|-|
 anything@another.tld|:|thomas|-|
 third@address.tld|:|kelly|-|
```

you can use `:` and `@` as delimiters and add data after it using awk, then save it to a new file,

```
awk -F '[@:]' '{ print $1"@"$2 ":|" $2"--" $3 }' file1 > file2
```

Above command saves following data in a file called `file2`,

```
something@nothing.tld|:|nothing.tld|--|george|-|
anything@another.tld|:|another.tld|--|thomas|-|
third@address.tld|:|address.tld|--|kelly|-|
```

Comment: You're the best! Works like a charm, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {print $1, $2, gensub(/.*@/,"",1,$1), "--", $3, $4, $5}' file
something@nothing.tld|:|nothing.tld|--|george|-|
anything@another.tld|:|another.tld|--|thomas|-|
third@address.tld|:|address.tld|--|kelly|-|
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {d=$1; sub(/.*@/,"",d); print $1, $2, d, "--", $3, $4, $5}' file
something@nothing.tld|:|nothing.tld|--|george|-|
anything@another.tld|:|another.tld|--|thomas|-|
third@address.tld|:|address.tld|--|kelly|-|
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/@([^|]+)\|:\|/&\1|--|/' infile
```

Note the use of a negated-group (`[^|]`), i.e. match anything except this character group.

Output:

```
something@nothing.tld|:|nothing.tld|--|george|-|
anything@another.tld|:|another.tld|--|thomas|-|
third@address.tld|:|address.tld|--|kelly|-|
```